Next Auth API routes 404 not found in production
It's working fine in local but when I deployed the app in production with the right url in .env, It won't let me sign in since it cannot find or access the api route in production.
69-70effe13903bb54a.js:1GET https://pulse.bayanibrands.com/api/auth/signin?callbackUrl=%2Fdashboard 404 (Not Found)
I suspect the middleware but can't find the wrong code
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";

export const config = { matcher: ["/dashboard"] };

I tried changing the middleware and no chance. It worked last time but now can't seem to fix it
